# Can an UEFI Ubuntu installation be converted into a BIOS installation?

Tags: boot, uefi

Because a rare behavior on one of my PCs, I have to installed Ubuntu with the UEFI way (because into the normal BIOS way, I just got a broken Windows start, because it had already been removed).

BTW: The thing was I don't have the original Windows installation disk to use the standard Windows uninstall process. So I had to created a new partition to Ubuntu and then to delete, manually, all the Windows folders and files from the Windows partition. I can not to format that Windows partition because I have a lot of very important data on that (music and videos) and I don't have any other device where to perform a backup, for the moment (it is more than 750 GB of data). So, when I installed Ubuntu, with the normal BIOS way, all the system was installed but.. when I reboot, the PC showed me an error message: Not system disk (I guess it still looked for the Windows installation). The only way I found to get the PC started with the new Ubuntu system was to install it into the UEFI way. That's my case.

Well, everything is fine and working OK, now, but... I wonder, just wonder, if there is a way to change the UEFI installation into a normal BIOS installation, if it was necessary (just in case), without to lose any, and without the annoying Windows starting error.

Can it be possible? How?

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!

Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ***get proper backup hardware!*** This site -- and indeed the Internet as a whole -- is littered with tales of woe from people who haven't backed up their critical data and, as a result, have lost it all. Don't become another person posting such a story!

Second, but related to that first point, if you no longer have a Windows installation, it's important that you move your personal files off of the Windows NTFS volume. The reason is that there is no Linux NTFS repair utility. Thus, when (note: *when*) the filesystem needs repair, you won't be able to do it from Linux. You'll have to boot a Windows emergency system or move the disk to another computer to do this job. This is a big hassle, and can be a little risky. (Note that there is a Linux tool called `ntfsfix`, but its name is misleading. This tool does only the most basic checks and then flags the disk as requiring attention from Windows. It can't actually repair filesystem damage.)

Finally, it is possible to convert a Linux installation made in EFI mode to boot in BIOS mode. Basically, you need to install a BIOS-mode boot loader to the disk. If you're booting via an EFI-mode GRUB 2 (as is the default), I do not recommend you use the BIOS-mode GRUB 2 for this, since the two GRUBs may try to use the same configuration file, but they've got somewhat different needs, so you can end up with a conflict and new problems. Instead, I recommend using GRUB Legacy, SYSLINUX, or LILO. There are numerous sites that describe how to install these tools, but I don't happen to have any bookmarks handy.

That said, unless you have a compelling need, I don't recommend you try setting this up. If you're booting correctly in EFI mode, attempting to install a BIOS-mode boot loader will take time and effort that might be better spent elsewhere. Worse, there's always a risk that you'll create problems for yourself, up to and including data loss -- which brings me back to my lead paragraph.

If you're concerned about your boot loader malfunctioning, you can download a USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a boot medium. You should be able to use rEFInd to boot your computer if GRUB malfunctions. (Of course, rEFInd's capabilities are limited. If there's a post-GRUB problem like bad filesystem damage, rEFInd won't help -- but then, neither would a BIOS-mode boot loader.)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You have to "iluminate" my great ignorance about these topics. Thank you so much, again!!!